# How to avoid "file has changed" warning when writing buffer?

Tags: external-command, save

I am using `system()` to change a buffer's file.  I apply the same change to the buffer itself.  I can't just reload the buffer because there are other unsaved changes.

When I come to write the buffer, Vim gives me:

```
WARNING: The file has changed since reading it!!!
Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?
```

I do really want to write to it.

How can I avoid this warning?

I have tried adding a `FileChangedShell` autocmd which doesn't do anything, but it does not get fired for `system()` calls.  So I added a `silent execute ':!'`, which seems to trigger the autocmd, but the screen gets all messed up – and vim still shows the warning.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's none of my business, but I'd love to know the context of why you're doing this.

Comment: I'm trying to add stashing to [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter).

Comment: Nice. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. I just read your "improvements" post, BTW, and thought, "I recognise that name..." So then I came back here to say: thanks for making git-gutter: it's one of my favourite plugins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to store the contents of the buffer, reload the file (to make vim happy), then restore the contents.

```
let lastline = line('$')
let bufcontents = getline(1, lastline)
edit!
call setline(1, bufcontents)
if line('$') > lastline
  execute lastline+1.',$:d _'
endif
```