# Write several files all of which have been changed since read

Tags: save

I opened several files in vim and then switched git branches. I want to save the versions I have open to the new git branch, for all of them, without having to silence the `WARNING: The file has changed since reading it!!!` for each of them individually. I am specifically interested in doing this for several files at once. Iterating over all buffers is unacceptable because that will write any file which was previously open in this vim session.

Answers [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15280/how-to-avoid-file-has-changed-warning-when-writing-buffer) only help for the single file case and provide no guidance on how to iterate it across many open files without collateral damage.

How do I do it?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: This is not the way to do this. You can checkout specific files from another branch or commit to the current branch.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15280/how-to-avoid-file-has-changed-warning-when-writing-buffer

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm asking about the many-files case.

Comment: What prevents you from using the answer in the dupe in a loop over all buffers?

Comment: Looping over all buffers currently open and only those is very difficult; everything I've tried to do that either only touches those buffers which are currently visible or touches every file which has been open at any point in this vim session.

Comment: Loop over all windows in all tabs and you have all visible buffers.

Comment: And a bunch more buffers which aren't visible which I do not want to touch

Comment: I still have no solution for this problem.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski I just saw your edit. I tried to address it, and voted to reopen

Comment: Appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

It is completely possible to build on the linked duplicate for a specific list of files.

We first extract the old code into a function that will operate on a given filename:

```
function! ReallyWrite(f) abort
  execute 'buffer' f
  let lastline = line('$')
  let bufcontents = getline(1, lastline)
  edit!
  call setline(1, bufcontents)
  if line('$') > lastline
    execute lastline+1.',$:d _'
  endif
endfunction
```

Then we write a command to do it for all the files we want:

```
command -nargs=+ -complete=file ReallyWrite for f in [<f-args>] | call ReallyWrite(f) | endfor
```

Usage: `:ReallyWrite file1 file2`

With some simple modifications, `ReallyWrite` could return to the old buffer after it is finished working. (I think you'd just have to do `buffer #` at the end of the function.)

---

This answer is a two-parter:

1. "Tricking" vim into not caring about the fact that files have changed
2. Using git properly to avoid this in the first place

## Vim

Reading [`:help :wall`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Awall) tells us that

```
Vim will warn you if you try to overwrite a file that has been changed
elsewhere.  See |timestamp|.
```

`:help timestamp` gives

```
If you do not want to be asked or automatically reload the file, you can use
this: 
        set buftype=nofile
```

Now, the problem with `buftype=nofile` is that the file

> will not be written ([`:help 'buftype'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27buftype%27))

So, the linked QA provides one answer (save and restore). My solution would be to set all buffers to `nofile` and then use `:w filename` (which should still work, according to the docs):

```
argdo set buftype=nofile | execute 'write' bufname('%')
```

*except* that, for some reason, the docs don't seem to be correct: the above command errors for each argument, even though `:write filename` is supposed to work. `:write othername` works, but you cannot write to the buffer name.

So I would use the linked answer.

## Git

I'm not sure how on-topic this part is, but it's an answer to the question, if a bit of a frame challenge.

You want to get (some of) the files in one branch (`to_update`) to have identical contents to the corresponding files on another branch (`stable`).

1. Checkout the `to_update` branch
2. Choose a strategy:

   - Merge the branches: `git merge stable`. You don't have control over which files change, and they won't be identical post-merge, but you do get the contents from the `stable` branch (integrated with `to_update`).
   - Checkout the files on another branch: `git checkout stable [files...]`. This makes `files` exactly as they are in `stable`, and lets you pick which files. No vim reloading necessary.

*Caveat:* if you have *already* edited the files, then you switch branches, you have a different problem. You wouldn't be allowed to switch branches if there were conflicts, so the vim method should work fine. If there were conflicts, do `git stash`, the use the second strategy for git, the `git stash apply` (followed by `git stash drop` if you're satisfied).

If you wish to edit the files that changed, you can do some parsing to get a list of changed files. I do this with my [`git-ed` script](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/bin/git-ed).

Comment: I virtually always want this in the situation you mention under "Caveat", in which case git can only do it as an awkward kludge.